# Regex to get extract parts from String with specific separator, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have example string:

```
[:pl]Field_value_in_PL[:en]Field_value_in_EN[:]
```

And I want get something like it:

```
Object {
    pl: "Field_value_in_PL",
    en: "Field_value_in_EN"
}
```

But I cannot assume there will be always "[:pl]" and "[:en]" in input string. There can by only :pl or :en, :de and :fr or any other combination.

I tried to write Regexp for this but I failed.

Comment: don't get discouraged, try again!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.match()` with `RegExp` `/:(\w{2})/g` to match `:` followed by two alphanumeric characters, `.map()` to iterate results returned from `.match()`, `String.prototype.slice()` to remove `:` from results, `.split()` with `RegExp` `/\[:\w{2}\]|\[:\]|:\w{2}/` to remove `[`, `]` characters and matched `:` followed by two alphanumeric characters, `.filter()` with `Boolean` as parameter to remove empty string from array returned by `.split()`, use `index` of `.map()` to set value of object, return object

```js
var str = "[:pl]Field_value_in_PL[:en]Field_value_in_EN[:]:deField_value_in_DE";

var props = str.match(/:(\w{2})/g).map(function(val, index) {
  var obj = {}
  , prop = val.slice(1)
  ,vals = str.split(/\[:\w{2}\]|\[:\]|:\w{2}/).filter(Boolean);
  obj[prop] = vals[index];
  return obj
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(props, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `String.replace` , `String.split` and `Array.forEach` functions:

```
var str = "[:pl]Field_value_in_PL[:en]Field_value_in_EN[:fr]Field_value_in_FR[:de]Field_value_in_DE[:]",
    obj = {},
    fragment = "";

var matches = str.replace(/\[:(\w+?)\]([a-zA-Z_]+)/gi, "$1/$2|").split('|');
matches.forEach(function(v){    // iterating through key/value pairs
    fragment = v.split("/");
    if (fragment.length == 2) obj[fragment[0]] = fragment[1];  // making sure that we have a proper 'final' key/value pair
});

console.log(obj);
// the output:
Object { pl: "Field_value_in_PL", en: "Field_value_in_EN", fr: "Field_value_in_FR", de: "Field_value_in_DE" }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex to capture in one group what's inside a pair of brackets and in the other group the group of words that follow the brackets.

`(\[.*?\])(\w+)`